# Object Dispose Exception in Android for Xamarin Forms Application

Tags: listview, exception, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

My team has stuck in this object dispose exception when we bind listliew with list of object data in Xamarin Forms application and target it to Android platform. It works perfectly fine in iOS platform.

Below is the error we receive,

```
    Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Android.Graphics.Bitmap'.
Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf(IJavaPeerable self)JniPeerMembers.cs:153
Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualInt32Method(string encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters)JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:217
Android.Graphics.Bitmap.get_Height()Android.Graphics.Bitmap.cs:375
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonDrawable.Draw(Canvas canvas)
Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.n_Draw_Landroid_graphics_Canvas_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_canvas)Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.cs:1301
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:7acab932-baad-4784-8862-7b9cef76d5f3 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ButtonDrawable.n_draw(Native Method)
md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ButtonDrawable.draw()ButtonDrawable.java:50
android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode()View.java:16421
android.view.View.drawBackground()View.java:16357
android.view.View.draw()View.java:16169
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15174
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15169
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.draw()View.java:16181
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15174
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15169
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.widget.ListView.drawChild()ListView.java:3416
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw()AbsListView.java:2591
android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw()ListView.java:3411
android.view.View.draw()View.java:16181
android.widget.AbsListView.draw()AbsListView.java:4142
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15174
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.draw()View.java:16181
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15174
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15169
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.draw()View.java:16181
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15174
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.draw()View.java:16181
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15174
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15169
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild()DrawerLayout.java:1373
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15169
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.draw()View.java:16181
com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw()ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:500
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15174
android.view.View.draw()View.java:15948
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild()ViewGroup.java:3609
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw()ViewGroup.java:3399
android.view.View.draw()View.java:16181
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw()PhoneWindow.java:2690
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty()View.java:15174
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList()ThreadedRenderer.java:281
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList()ThreadedRenderer.java:287
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw()ThreadedRenderer.java:322
android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw()ViewRootImpl.java:2615
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw()ViewRootImpl.java:2434
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()ViewRootImpl.java:2067
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal()ViewRootImpl.java:1107
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run()ViewRootImpl.java:6013
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run()Choreographer.java:858
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks()Choreographer.java:670
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame()Choreographer.java:606
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run()Choreographer.java:844
android.os.Handler.handleCallback()Handler.java:739
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:95
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:148
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:5417
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()ZygoteInit.java:726
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:616
```

This error is very random and crashes the whole application. We are not binding any image to list. List has text labels, FontAwesome icon labels and buttons.

Since, this exception only occur at run time so this exception could not be handled.

Kindly help.

Comment: Please upload a sample project and relevant sample code to help others investigate.

Comment: I believe it has to do with https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42678